# How to parse parameter pack as template parameter

Tags: c++

everyone.Recently I want to write a function to count time consumption in most common cases.

```
template<typename ReturnType, typename... ArgList>
int64_t TimeCount(function<ReturnType(ArgList...)> f, ArgList... args) {
    auto t0 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f(std::forward<ArgList>(args)...);
    auto t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    cout << "cost " << duration << "ms " << endl;
    return duration;
}
```

But with the code above, only somthing like`candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (type-parameter-0-1...)>' against 'void (*)(int (*)(std::vector<long> &, int, int), std::vector<long> &, int, int)'` can I get, Is there any way to make the code work correctly?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

Issues with

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... ArgList>
int64_t TimeCount(std::function<ReturnType(ArgList...)> f, ArgList... args)
```

are

- that `ArgList` should be deduced from 2 places and should be identical.
- lambda/function pointers are NOT `std::function`, and disallow deduction.

You might use instead:

```
template <typename F, typename... ArgList>
int64_t TimeCount(F f, ArgList&&... args)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I know very little about the template deduction, I should learn more about template.